# Appium android application not opened

Tags: python, appium

So I have created simple automation to open a calculator on my phone using Appium and python, the code does not have any error but I don't know why the application is not opened. I have tried using java language it is work, the application can be opened.

```
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps = dict(
    platformName='Android',
    platformVersion='10.0',
    deviceName='MI 8 SE',
    deviceId='ccbcab1',
    appPacckage='com.miui.calculator',
    appActivity='.cal.AllInOneCalculatorActivity',
    skipUnlock='True',
    noReset='False'
)

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

Also here the Appium console

```
[Appium] ======================================================================
[Appium] 
[Appium] Appium v1.15.1 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.37.2) session
[BaseDriver] Creating session with MJSONWP desired capabilities: {
[BaseDriver]   "platformName": "Android",
[BaseDriver]   "platformVersion": "10.0",
[BaseDriver]   "deviceName": "MI 8 SE",
[BaseDriver]   "deviceId": "ccbcab1",
[BaseDriver]   "appPacckage": "com.miui.calculator",
[BaseDriver]   "appActivity": ".cal.AllInOneCalculatorActivity\"",
[BaseDriver]   "skipUnlock": "True",
[BaseDriver]   "noReset": "False"
[BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] Capability 'noReset' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
[BaseDriver] Capability 'skipUnlock' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by Appium:
[BaseDriver]   deviceId
[BaseDriver]   appPacckage
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 80e56167-920e-4713-8d33-88e6e3a98138
[UiAutomator2] Neither 'app' nor 'appPackage' was set. Starting UiAutomator2 without the target application
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"ccbcab1","state":"device"},{"udid":"192.168.0.100:5555","state":"device"}]
[AndroidDriver] Looking for a device with Android '10.0'
[ADB] Setting device id to ccbcab1
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 10
[AndroidDriver] Using device: ccbcab1
[ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
[ADB] Setting device id to ccbcab1
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 29
[ADB] Device API level: 29
[UiAutomator2] Relaxing hidden api policy
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps 1'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell settings put global hidden_api_policy 1'
[AndroidDriver] No app sent in, not parsing package/activity
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 wait-for-device'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell echo ping'
[AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] Cannot extract apk info using apkanalyzer. Falling back to aapt. Original error: Could not find 'apkanalyzer.bat' in ["C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\emulator\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\tools\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\tools\\bin\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\30.0.0-rc3\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\29.0.3\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\25.0.2\\apkanalyzer.bat"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'?
[ADB] Using 'aapt.exe' from 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0-rc3\aapt.exe'
[ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the application version name ('2.14.2' >= '2.14.2')
[ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'io.appium.settings' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell 'pgrep --help; echo $?''
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell pgrep -f io\\.appium\\.settings'
[AndroidDriver] io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions.
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell appops set io.appium.settings android\:mock_location allow'
[Logcat] Starting logcat capture
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[ADB] 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server'
[ADB] Cannot extract apk info using apkanalyzer. Falling back to aapt. Original error: Could not find 'apkanalyzer.bat' in ["C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\emulator\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\tools\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\tools\\bin\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\30.0.0-rc3\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\29.0.3\\apkanalyzer.bat","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\25.0.2\\apkanalyzer.bat"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'?
[ADB] The version name of the installed 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' is greater or equal to the application version name ('4.3.0' >= '4.3.0')
[UiAutomator2] io.appium.uiautomator2.server installation state: sameVersionInstalled
[ADB] Checking app cert for C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.3.0.apk
[ADB] Using 'apksigner.bat' from 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0-rc3\apksigner.bat'
[ADB] Starting 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0-rc3\apksigner.bat' with args '["verify","--print-certs","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.3.0.apk"]'
[ADB] apksigner stdout: Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: a40da80a59d170caa950cf15c18c454d47a39b26989d8b640ecd745ba71bf5dc
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 61ed377e85d386a8dfee6b864bd85b0bfaa5af81
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: e89b158e4bcf988ebd09eb83f5378e87
[ADB] 
[ADB] 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.3.0.apk' is already signed.
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell dumpsys package io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test'
[ADB] 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' is installed
[ADB] Checking app cert for C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk
[ADB] Starting 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0-rc3\apksigner.bat' with args '["verify","--print-certs","C:\\Users\\Ilham_R121\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk"]'
[ADB] apksigner stdout: Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: a40da80a59d170caa950cf15c18c454d47a39b26989d8b640ecd745ba71bf5dc
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 61ed377e85d386a8dfee6b864bd85b0bfaa5af81
[ADB] Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: e89b158e4bcf988ebd09eb83f5378e87
[ADB] 
[ADB] 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' is already signed.
[UiAutomator2] Server packages are not going to be (re)installed
[UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 30000ms for services to be available
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell pm list instrumentation'
[UiAutomator2] Instrumentation target 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner' is available
[UiAutomator2] Forwarding UiAutomator2 Server port 6790 to 8204
[ADB] Forwarding system: 8204 to device: 6790
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 forward tcp\:8204 tcp\:6790'
[UiAutomator2] No app capability. Assuming it is already on the device
[UiAutomator2] Performing shallow cleanup of automation leftovers
[UiAutomator2] No obsolete sessions have been detected (Error: socket hang up)
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ccbcab1 shell am force-stop io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test'
[UiAutomator2] Starting UIAutomator2 server 4.3.0
[UiAutomator2] Using UIAutomator2 server from 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.3.0.apk' and test from 'C:\Users\Ilham_R121\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
[UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 30000ms for UiAutomator2 to be online...
[ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ccbcab1","shell","am","instrument","-w","io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"]
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8204/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response with status undefined: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[Instrumentation] io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test.AppiumUiAutomator2Server:
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8204/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response with status undefined: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8204/wd/hub/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"None","value":{"ready":true,"message":"UiAutomator2 Server is ready to accept commands"}}
[UiAutomator2] The initialization of the instrumentation process took 3075ms
[WD Proxy] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8204/wd/hub/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"10.0","deviceName":"MI 8 SE","deviceId":"ccbcab1","appPacckage":"com.miui.calculator","appActivity":".cal.AllInOneCalculatorActivity\"","skipUnlock":true,"noReset":false},"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"10.0","deviceName":"ccbcab1","deviceId":"ccbcab1","appPacckage":"com.miui.calculator","appActivity":".cal.AllInOneCalculatorActivity\"","skipUnlock":true,"noReset":false,"deviceUDID":"ccbcab1"}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"58e5b0ca-19fb-4989-963f-930109b4c250","value":{"sessionId":"58e5b0ca-19fb-4989-963f-930109b4c250","capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"10.0","deviceName":"MI 8 SE","deviceId":"ccbcab1","appPacckage":"com.miui.calculator","appActivity":".cal.AllInOneCalculatorActivity\"","skipUnlock":true,"noReset":false},"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"10.0","deviceName":"ccbcab1","deviceId":"ccbcab1","appPacckage":"com.miui.calculator","appActivity":".cal.AllInOneCalculatorActivity\"","skipUnlock":true,"noReset":false,"deviceUDID":"ccbcab1"}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}}
[WD Proxy] Determined the downstream protocol as 'W3C'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /appium/device/info] to [GET http://localhost:8204/wd/hub/session/58e5b0ca-19fb-4989-963f-930109b4c250/appium/device/info] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"58e5b0ca-19fb-4989-963f-930109b4c250","value":{"androidId":"f75034e0af8ac546","manufacturer":"Xiaomi","model":"MI 8 SE","brand":"Xiaomi","apiVersion":"29","platformVersion":"10","carrierName":"Tsel-DiRumahAja","realDisplaySize":"1080x2244","displayDensity":440,"networks":[{"type":1,"typeName":"WIFI","subtype":0,"subtypeName":"","isConnected":true,"detailedState":"CONNECTED","state":"CONNECTED","extraInfo":null,"isAvailable":true,"isFailover":false,"isRoaming":false,"capabilities":{"transportTypes":"NET_CAPABILITY_SUPL","networkCapabilities":"","linkUpstreamBandwidthKbps":1048576,"linkDownBandwidthKbps":1048576,"signalStrength":-53,"networkSpecifier":null,"SSID":null}}],"locale":"en_GB","timeZone":"Asia\/Jakarta"}}
[UiAutomator2] 'skipUnlock' capability set, so skipping device unlock
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /appium/device/pixel_ratio] to [GET http://localhost:8204/wd/hub/session/58e5b0ca-19fb-4989-963f-930109b4c250/appium/device/pixel_ratio] with body: {}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"58e5b0ca-19fb-4989-963f-930109b4c250","value":2.75}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/appium/device/system_bars' to command name 'getSystemBars'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /appium/device/system_bars] to [GET http://localhost:8204/wd/hub/session/58e5b0ca-19fb-4989-963f-930109b4c250/appium/device/system_bars] with body: {}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"58e5b0ca-19fb-4989-963f-930109b4c250","value":{"statusBar":85}}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/window/current/size' to command name 'getWindowSize'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /window/current/size] to [GET http://localhost:8204/wd/hub/session/58e5b0ca-19fb-4989-963f-930109b4c250/window/current/size] with body: {}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"58e5b0ca-19fb-4989-963f-930109b4c250","value":{"height":2029,"width":1080}}
[Appium] New AndroidUiautomator2Driver session created successfully, session 80e56167-920e-4713-8d33-88e6e3a98138 added to master session list
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1591869560565 (17:59:20 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time))
[MJSONWP (80e56167)] Cached the protocol value 'MJSONWP' for the new session 80e56167-920e-4713-8d33-88e6e3a98138
[MJSONWP (80e56167)] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"10.0","deviceName":"MI 8 SE","deviceId":"ccbcab1","appPacckage":"com.miui.calculator","appActivity":".cal.AllInOneCalculatorActivity\"","skipUnlock":true,"noReset":false},"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"10","deviceName":"ccbcab1","deviceId":"ccbcab1","appPacckage":"com.miui.calculator","appActivity":".cal.AllInOneCalculatorActivity\"","skipUnlock":true,"noReset":false,"deviceUDID":"ccbcab1","deviceApiLevel":29,"deviceScreenSize":"1080x2244","deviceScreenDensity":440,"deviceModel":"MI 8 SE","deviceManufacturer":"Xiaomi","pixelRatio":2.75,"statBarHeight":85,"viewportRect":{"left":0,"top":85,"width":1080,"height":1944}}
```

I don't know why the calculator can't lanuch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`Appium Desired Capabilities`**](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/)

This log very clear:

```
[BaseDriver] Capability 'noReset' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
[BaseDriver] Capability 'skipUnlock' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
```

You have errors in capabilities, remove quotes `'` to become boolean, it's should:

```
skipUnlock=True
noReset=False
```

And the below:

```
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by Appium:
[BaseDriver]   deviceId
[BaseDriver]   appPacckage
```

`deviceId` should be `udid`, and `appPacckage` (excess c) should be `appPackage`.

Try the below capabilities:

```
desired_caps = dict(
    platformName='Android',
    platformVersion='10.0',
    deviceName='MI 8 SE',
    udid='ccbcab1',
    appPackage='com.miui.calculator',
    appActivity='.cal.AllInOneCalculatorActivity',
    skipUnlock=True,
    noReset=False
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. appPackage is wrong typo
   appPacckage='com.miui.calculator',
2. appActivity='.cal.CalculatorActivity',

Boom! Calculator opened in your phone ^^